# Seamlessly passing drag&drop actions from children controls to parent ScatterViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, touch, pixelsense

I am using Surface 2.0 SDK and my application uses dynamically created custom controls which consist of a `ScatterViewItem` which holds a `Grid` with a `Menu` inside each column.

When initiating a drag&drop motion on any area inside the `ScatterViewItem` including the `Grid`, or the margins around the `Menu`, the `ScatterViewItem` is being dragged along nicely together with its contents.
However, when trying to initiate such a motion anywhere inside the `Menu` control, nothing happens. It seems like the necessary events are being swallowed by it.

I have tried extending the `Menu` class to create a custom control and use a `RoutedEvent` to handle captured mouse clicks within the `ScatterViewItem`, but can't quite find a way to seamlessly handle drag events and pass them on to the parent `ScatterViewItem`

Can anyone share some knowledge on how to implement this?